# Program To Display Tea Brands Which Have Sold Over 500 Tea Bags C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, c++11

Cannot Seem To Get The Output, Dont Know Why
I Have tried using Arrays and For loops and cant seem to understand why I am not getting the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
int count;
int final;
cout<<"Enter The Amount Of Tea Brands"<<endl;
cin>>count;

string Brand [count];
int Amount [count];
string Output [100];

for(int i =0;i<count;i++) {
    cout<<"Enter Brand Name"<<endl;
    cin>>Brand[i];
    for(int j =0; j<count; j++){
        cout<<"Enter Sold"<<endl;
        cin>>Amount[j];
        break;
    }       
}

for(int k=0; k<count; k++){
    if (Amount[k]>500){
        Brand[k]=Output[k];
    }
}

for (int l=0; l<count; l++){
    cout<<Output[l];
}
```

}

Comment: If the user says there are, say, 10 tea brands, the program then prompts them for 10 amounts **for each brand**; 100 amounts total. Did you mean it this way? In any case, all these amounts are written to the same array of 10 values; what's left in Amount at the end is the 10 values entered for the last brand.

Comment: `Output` is an array of empty strings; nowhere in the program have they been assigned any value. So the very last loop - the only place that produces output - just prints `count` empty strings. Did you perhaps mean `Output[k] = Brand[k];` in the next-to-last loop?

Comment: I have made the output loop separate to collect the brands that obey the condition of if (Amount[k]>500). When this condition is true, I initialize the statement Brand[k]=Output[k];. This in my mind copy the respective value to the output array, therefore it can then be printed when required then.

Comment: In `Brand[k]=Output[k];`, what do you believe gets assigned to what else? Where is the value comping from, and what variable is modified and set to that value?

Comment: I have made 2 arrays one containing the brand name and one containing the amount sold. Then use a nested for loop starting form 0(because array index starts from 0) to first ask the user the brand name and then ask the amount sold and store them into their respective arrays with the same index. I then compare the values using a for loop and an if statement. if the condition is true I assign the value of respective index to the the output array(There is an error in the code it should be Output[k] = Brand[k] however I have made this change and nothing has changed).

Comment: Finally I would like to print the values that are in the Ouput Array. If possible could be Zoom as It would make it easier Thanks.

Comment: If the user enters `10` for `count`, how many times, in total, is the line `cout<<"Enter Sold"<<endl;` executed? How many times do you expect it to be executed?

Comment: I expect it go 10 times

Comment: Now I understand. You break out of the inner loop (the one over `j`) on the very first iteration. `j` is always zero, you read all the amounts into `Amount[0]`. Of course, only the last-read value is stored there. All the other elements of `Amount` are uninitialized, containing random garbage.

Comment: I have figured out the issue it was the break statement. I actually overcomplicated the problem in reality it is very simple. Thank you for your time though I really appreciate it.